# Istio WorkloadEntry sidecar a requirements?

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

I'm interested in putting a vendor provided application running in an AWS EC2 Instance behind my Istio gateway. It sounds like the ideal scenario is to use a WorkloadEntry to define the endpoint and make it easy to flex should I ever get this into the cluster, etc.

In the documentation I've read, there is mention of using a sidecar in the VM to enable this. What I've failed to find is how to use a sidecar in a VM. There's lots of good stuff about sidecars in a pod, but I'm not sure what it takes to implement on the VM and how I would even go about doing that. Maybe the integration needed for the sidecar would be to complex to implement in a 3rd party app? Maybe I can do this better without a Sidecar?

How do I find details on VM Sidecars and getting them integrated into the mesh?

When do you decide between implementing this as a WorkloadEntry vs simply a MESH_EXTERNAL ServiceEntry?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate a VM into your k8s Istio environment, you need to setup Istio on your VM :
https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/vm-architecture/